# изменение содержимого страницы без участия пользователя

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Хочу написать небольшую браузерную игру для своих детей, типа викторины с логическими вопросами. У меня есть небольшой опыт в создании сайтов, работы с PHP и JS. Но я не знаю или не понимаю как делают, что изменяется страница в одного пользователя, в зависимости от действий других пользователей. Игра будет типа как бой в режиме реального времени между двумя игроками. Для меня загадка как без обновления и/или нажатий на разные кнопки (ссылки) страницы E-mail-сервиса мне показывает об получении нового письма?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, от куда начинать копать, что читать? Спасибо.

Comment: Могу попробовать толкнуть вас сразу вот сюда: http://socketo.me/ ... с его первоначальным примером простого чата на вебсокетах http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world ..... а также посмотреть видео о создании чата на этой библиотеке https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYpSG5d5IPk  и скачать файлы https://github.com/muuknl/phprealtimechat ...чтобы посмотреть их..... и на основе этого сделать подобное..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой  вариант это опрашивать сервер с установленным промежутком времени для этого можно использовать [AJAX](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81).
Есть варианты изощренней с использованием [WebSocket](https://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/). На стороне клиента тоже можно их использовать можно почитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets).

Comment: AJAX не лучший вариант использования. Лучше использовать WebSocket`ы

Comment: @Shnur не самый лучший но простой.

Comment: я так и понимал, что должен быть вопрос-ответ и потому сам думал про AJAX. Но меня смущает, что постоянно будет опрашиватся сервер через, например 5 сек. Не сильно ли это загрузит трафик и вообще сам клиент?

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра да не должен если два игрока, да и вы можете минимизировать данные отправляемые на сервер.

Answer (score -1):

```
JS
setInterval function
AngularJS
$interval
```

На Front End внутри setInterval делаем ajax запрос на backend

сервер сравнивает изменения реквеста и данных из БД

усли разные то отдать response типа newData true + data

затем меняем на станице и ставим флаг newData = false и т.п.

Гуглописари webworker используют можно почитать или вбейте в поиск типа пуллер

Comment: ты хоть сам понял, что ты написал?